# algorithm finding an output from a group of expert

Tags: algorithm, forecasting

I have a group of experts and their reputation (if any) who can predict a binary output. What will be the best approach to forecast the most likely output from there based on the experts recommandation?

[image]

Comment: Hi Matel, you just have one result for each expert? Because using forecasting starting from one value does not have much sense.
or i did not get your question?

Comment: yes I am studying the output at this time given, I was thinking of a forecasting based on the number of experts rather than the history of each expert outputs ? For instance if all the experts have a consensus of 1 then the likely output is 1. In addition the reputation might help to have some information with regards to the history of each experts. I mean an expert with a high reputation should be more likely to be right in his forecast.

Comment: A possible approach might be to sum the expert reputations grouped by output. Then take the output with the maximum total reputation. Whether or not this is reasonable depends on what these numbers represent.

Comment: it is a nice simplification I didn't think of. Thanks.